# Android drawing grid in background

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to draw grid (just 8x8 lines) in background, but my drawing view covers it and grid doesn't show up. My DrawingView handles touches and draws circles. Grid must draw grids in background (it does when DrawingView is gone).

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RelativeLayout layout;
private DrawingView drawingView;
private FloatingActionButton pickPhoto;
private final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    pickPhoto = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.insertPhoto);
    drawingView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawingView);
    assert drawingView != null;
    drawingView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    pickPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Save")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_save)
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    FloatingActionMenu fab = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                    assert fab != null;
                    fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(layout);
                    saveChart(bitmap, layout.getMeasuredHeight(), layout.getMeasuredWidth());
                    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .setShowAsAction(
                    MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                            | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void saveChart(Bitmap getbitmap, float height, float width) {
    File folder = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "My drawings");

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    File file = new File(folder.getPath() + File.separator + "/" + timeStamp + ".png");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream ostream;

    try {
        ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Bitmap save = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Canvas now = new Canvas(save);
        now.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height), paint);
        now.drawBitmap(getbitmap,
                new Rect(0, 0, getbitmap.getWidth(), getbitmap.getHeight()),
                new Rect(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height), null);
        save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
    } catch (NullPointerException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(RelativeLayout layout) {
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    layout.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache());
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bmp;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    drawingView.setImage(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
    }
}
```

}

DrawingView.java:

```
class DrawingView extends SurfaceView {

private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private ArrayList<Point> points;
private Bitmap mBitmap;

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    points = new ArrayList<>();
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mBitmap != null)
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    for (Point p : points)
        canvas.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 50, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    points.add(new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));
    invalidate();
    return false;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    mBitmap = bitmap;
    invalidate();
}
```

}

Grid.java:

```
public class Grid extends View{

private int rowsCount = 8;
private int columnsCount = 8;
private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

public Grid(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int height = getHeight();
    int width = getWidth();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; ++i) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, height / rowsCount * (i + 1), width, height / rowsCount * (i + 1), paint);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < columnsCount; ++i) {
        canvas.drawLine(width / columnsCount * (i + 1), 0, width / columnsCount * (i + 1), height, paint);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<reminder.com.paint.Grid
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <reminder.com.paint.DrawingView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawingView"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#DA4336"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#E75043"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99f47070"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/insertPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_photo_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Add photos" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addCircle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness_1_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Add circles" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you just draw the grid in `DrawingView`, as well? Also, are you sure you need a `SurfaceView` for that?

Comment: Because it's easy to save the drawing. Just need to delete the grid and save.

Comment: OK. Are you sure you need `DrawingView` to be a `SurfaceView`? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: What it has to be?

Comment: Why not just a regular `View`, like `Grid`? Then just set its background to transparent.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: `SurfaceView`s are meant to use a separate thread for rendering; e.g., for games, videos, etc. You're just doing a simple drawing app, and you're not using a separate thread, so extending a `SurfaceView` is overhead you don't need, and getting one to cooperate with other `View`s is more work than just using a regular `View`.

Comment: You're settIng the background to white in the code, too. You need to change that, or just remove it.

Comment: When I remove that background becomes black.

Comment: Then you're still extending `SurfaceView`. You need to do both things. Change `DrawingView` to extend `View`, and set its background to transparent.

Comment: Yeah that solves the thing, but they say that SurfaceView is good for drawings so I made my DrawingView extends SurfaceView.

Comment: A `SurfaceView` is only effective if you implement the worker thread that its rendering operations are meant to run on. If you're just doing a simple Paint-type app, then a regular `View` is usually sufficient. You can always refactor your app to use a `SurfaceView` later, if you find that what you want to do is causing lag in a regular `View`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Paint mPaintGridLine;  
... 
mPaintGridLine = new Paint();
mPaintGridLine.setColor(Color.WHITE);
mPaintGridLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaintGridLine.setStrokeWidth(1);
...

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    final int w = getWidth();
    final int h = getHeight();

    final int colCount = 10;     
    final int rowCount = 10;    

    // vertical lines

    final int vLinesCount = colCount - 1;
    for (int i=0; i<vLinesCount; i++)
    {
        float pos = (w / colCount) * (i + 1);
        canvas.drawLine(pos, 0, pos, h, mPaintGridLine);
    }

    // horizontal lines

    final int hLinesCount = rowCount - 1;
    for (int i=0; i<hLinesCount; i++)
    {
        float pos = (h / rowCount) * (i + 1);
        canvas.drawLine(0, pos, w, pos, mPaintGridLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).